# Cannot retrieve json string from php using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I can't retrieve json string data from my php script using ajax call.

Here is my ajax script :

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            dataType: "json",
            url: "database/clientpanel/logs/search_call_log.php",
            data: {
                from: from,
                to: to,
                sel: sel
                },
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){
                $("#app_panel").append(data.html);
                $('.inv_date').hide();
            }
        });
```

and this is my php script:

```
<?php
//wall ===================================================
session_start();
include("../../dbinfo.inc.php");
    $from = $_POST['from'];
    $to = $_POST['to'];
    $sel = $_POST['sel'];
// connect to the database
  $client_id = $_SESSION['clientid'];
  $out = 0;
  $in = 0;
  $ext =0;
  $min = 0;
  $sec = 0;
  $results = array(
  'html' => $html
  );    

  $html = " ";
    if($sel == "all"){
  $query=" select * from call where client='$client_id' ORDER BY date_time DESC";
  $result = $mysqli->query($query);
  }else{
  $query=" select * from tele_panel_call where (client='$client_id' AND date_time BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to') ORDER BY date_time DESC";
  $result = $mysqli->query($query);
  }  
        if ($result->num_rows > 0){ 

                                        while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
                                        {
                                        $from = $row->from;
                                        $to = $row->to;

                                    $html .= '<div style="width:590px;height:15px;background: url(img/clientimg/wrap-white.png)repeat;padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;margin-bottom:5px;">';

                                            $query_from=" select * from tele_agent_dialer where (client='$client_id' AND (dialer='$from' OR dialer='$to'))";
                                            $result_from = $mysqli->query($query_from);
                                            $row_from = $result_from->fetch_assoc();
                                            $dialer = $row_from['dialer'];
                                            if($dialer == $from){
                                            $image = 'outgoing';
                                            $out = $out+1;
                                            }
                                            if($dialer == $to){
                                            $image = 'incoming';
                                            $in = $in+1;
                                            }
                                            if($dialer != $to & $dialer != $from){
                                            $image = 'extension';
                                            $ext = $ext+1;
                                            }
                                    $html .= '<img src="img/clientimg/';  $html .= $image; $html .= '.png" style="float:left;margin-right:10px;height:15px">';
                                    $html .= '<div style="float:left;margin-right:5px;width:135px;height:30px;overflow:hidden;"><b>From: </b>';  
                                            if(  preg_match( '/^\d(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})$/', $from,  $matches ) )
                                            {
                                                $from = '('. $matches[1] . ') ' .$matches[2] . '-' . $matches[3];
                                            }
                                            $html .=  $from; 
                                    $html .= '</div>
                                            <div style="float:left;margin-right:5px;width:125px;height:30px;overflow:hidden;">
                                            <b>To: </b>';
                                            if(  preg_match( '/^\d(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})$/', $to,  $matches ) )
                                            {
                                                $to = '('. $matches[1] . ') ' .$matches[2] . '-' . $matches[3];
                                            }
                                            $html .=  $to; 
                                    $html .= '</div>
                                            <div style="float:left;width:160px;margin-right:5px;height:30px;overflow:hidden;">
                                            <b>Date/Time: </b>'; $html .=  $row->date_time; 
                                    $html .= '</div>
                                            <div style="float:left;width:100px;margin-right:5px;height:30px;overflow:hidden;">
                                            <b>Duration: </b>';
                                            $duration = $row->duration;
                                            preg_match("#(\d+):(\d+)#", $duration,  $matches );
                                            $min = $min + $matches[1];
                                            $sec = $sec + $matches[2];
                                            $html .=  $duration; 
                                    $html .= '</div>';
                                    $html .= '</div>';

                                        }

     }else{
     echo "No results to display!";
     }  



$jsonString = json_encode($results);
echo $jsonString;

$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here? My php script doesn't have any errors when I check the page itself.

Comment: are the php script and this ajax on same domain?

Comment: Obviously it's the PHP script that is causing this, or it wouldn't show "No results to display!". Does your database have any actual data in it?

Comment: @DavidHarris it says no results on the actual page that means there is no error on the script.

Comment: If that's your logic, then it is is doing exactly what it should.

Comment: @moonwave99 sorry for being such a noob, thats exactly what i'm doing learning from scratch, sorry if i didn't meet your expectations oh great and humble one.

Comment: Don't worry about that dude Telexper, not everyone on this site is all that friendly unfortunately. Do you have data in your table you're selecting from?

Comment: yes i have data on it, before i used json on my ajax i first testedd it using "function(html)" and all works fine, but when i switched to json, i can't retrieve any data from it.

Comment: @telexper I produced code similar to yours *for years*. Then someone advised me to learn from scratch and to use good approaches, and my workflow improved. Instead of providing you a quick and dirty solution to a localized problem, I advised you to go for a different approach overall, that's it - sorry if I appeared rude or anything, that was not my intention.

Comment: @moonwave99 i'm still learning to crawl, just started a month ago with no one teaching me anything about this, i'm learning from some old sources here and there ,and people here that are willing to give some guidance, so please excuse my script for the meantime, after learning to create then i'll try to make things improve bit by bit and clean up my script.

Answer (score 0):

Also it's good to add proper header for json data output (at the begining of the script for example).

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
```

As for query results, you should debug it. Try to print the query and run it in Phpmyadmin (or other database administration tool)